# analysis of categorical data for behaviour experiment

Tags: r, categorical-data, missing-data

I have been stuck on how to analyse my data for many weeks. My dataset consist of 13 variables all of which are categorical. 3 variables details the continent, population and type of treatment of my samples. The other 10 variables corresponds to each character e.g. variable 1= character 1, variable 2= character 2 etc. Under each of these variables, I have a few character states. e.g. character 1 have 4 states, state 1.5,2 and 0.1, character 2 have 3 states 1, 0.1 and 2 etc.

Background of my project:
I am working with flies and conducting a manipulative experiment on them to observe if there are any behavioural changes due to the treatment. Treatment consists of amputation of the middle and hind legs.

Here lies the problem. As some character describes the movement of middle legs/ hind legs, they are not applicable to the respective treatment groups as there is no basis of comparison. For E.g., character 4 involves the tapping of the male's middle leg to the female's thorax. For treatment 2 then, all my individuals for the variable, character 4 will be NAs.

The aim of the analysation is to see which character/character states draw my control and treatment groups apart, if any, such that I can see clusters. sort of like running a MCA.

The dataset looks something like this: 
[image]

so s1= state 1, s1.5= state 1.5

What I tried:
MCA--> however this treats NAs as an additional category which is not what I want 
MCA using missMDA package--> however, I realise that they treat NAs not as true NAs, (please do correct me if i'm wrong!) but more like no opinion or don't know. However, the NAs in my dataset are true missing values.

In this case, I feel that it is impossible to analyse this dataset as a whole and it might be more appropriate to split it into a control vs individual treatment analysation. This way, I do not have to include the characters which cannot be compared for specific treatment (thus no more NAs!) and can run a normal MCA on them.

However, this is just based on my very very limited knowledge of stats analysis using r so I might have missed out other possibilities. Is there any other way to analyse my dataset? Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: In the documentation of `MCA()` , there is an example that handled missing values with `missMDA::imputeMCA()`  take a look at the last example here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FactoMineR/versions/1.41/topics/MCA

Comment: Hello! I tried using it before however, the function imputeMCA requires an input ncp= which requires us to compute the number of dimensions using the function estim_ncpMCA. However, when I ran estim_ncpMCA with my dataset, I always get an error: Error in imputeMCA(as.data.frame(donNA), ncp = nbaxes, method = method,  : 
  The algorithm fails to converge. Choose a number of components (ncp) less or equal than 1 or a number of iterations (maxiter) less or equal than 999 // OR another error code Error in while (continue) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed//

Comment: I try to take these kind of questions as exercises, so I can't promise a solution, however understanding the experiment and the goal of the analysis would help me and other people who are trying to help you. So bear with me here as I'm trying to understand more, what are exactly those `characters`? are those two types of treatments in any way related? what do you see the meaning of `NA` in your data? and how do you think it should be treated in the analysis if not as its own level?

Comment: Hello, apologies for the late reply. I would say these individual characters are dependent variables (behaviours) that I am trying to measure, I wanted to see if the treatment causes any changes in behaviour in individual mating trials. and as a whole, I wanted to see if there was any character/characters that is able to differentiate my control and treatment groups. the types of treatment should not be related, as one only amputes the middle leg and the other only the hind leg.

Comment: Na in my data means we have no way of collecting data from that trial since for e.g( we cannot expect a individual with amputed middle leg to display behaviours involving the middle leg). I feel that it should be excluded in the analysis for its own specific treatment for e.g. I will exclude the characters that involve the middle leg when comparing control and treatment which involves amputation of the middle leg. exclude characters that involve the hind leg when comparing control and treatment which involves amputation of the hind leg.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error: "Error in imputeMCA(as.data.frame(donNA), ncp = nbaxes, method = method, : The algorithm fails to converge. Choose a number of components (ncp) less or equal than 1 or a number of iterations (maxiter) less or equal than 999"

I fixed it when I deleted redundant factor levels from my variables. i.e.: I had 50 questions answered by 60 experts; each question was on the same likert scale ; -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3.
I first had each of the scores as a factor variable with levels -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3. But some questions only had score 1,2, and 3 (for instance). When I deleted factor levels -3,-2,-1, and 0 for that particular variable, for instance, the function did work.